# How do I use except on a nested hash in a reject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, nested

I'm trying to reject an empty form entry, but I'm having difficulties.

Users can either choose for an existing location, or create a new one. I want the form to actually show empty fields, but reject them when they are all empty. As '_destroy' will never be empty, I need to make an exception. Also if only the quantity is filled out, the entry can be rejected.

The form submits the following information:

Parameters:

```
{"product"=>
        {..., 
        "product_locations_attributes"=>
            {
            "0"=>{"location_attributes"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "street"=>"", "number"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "city"=>"", "country"=>""}, "quantity"=>""},
            "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "location_id"=>"", "quantity"=>""}}
            }
        , "commit"=>"Create Product"
        }
```

AI'm trying to get the empty location removed in the Product model as follows:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_locations, :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if =>  proc {|a| a.except('_destroy', 'quantity').values.all?( &:blank? )}
```

As it is nested, it doesn't work like this.
So how can I check if everything is blank except the quantity and _destroy?
It should be possible to do it in one go right?
Thanks for any help.

*** updated to make it more clear ***

Comment: The data, as you've written it, is an `Array`. Did you mean to provide a `Hash`?

Comment: Hmm, good point. Perhaps I need to look into this a better to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Fritzz Within `proc`, is `a` that array?

Comment: I've updated the question now, hopefully making it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the anser of @RobHeaton I finally was able to make this work. Myabe his answer could work, but it did not work for me. If it should and I did something wrong, let me know, and I will accept his answer. I finally got it to work with the following code:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_locations, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :empty_fields

  def empty_fields(a)
    if la = a[:location_attributes]
      la[:street].blank? && la[:number].blank? && la[:city].blank? && la[:zipcode].blank? && la[:country].blank?
    else
      a[:location_id].blank?
    end
  end
```

It is now very clear on what needs to be blank in order for it to reject. With other things I tried I ended up with either too many things accepted or rejected.
Just writing this down in case other people run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly check all the fields that may or may not be blank, rather than try and do some kind of "are they all blank". Much more explicit and readable.

```
:reject_if =>  proc {|a| 
  location_attributes = a[:location_attributes]
  a[:street].blank? && a[:number].blank? && a[:location_id].blank?
}
```

It will be verbose but better in the long run!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was going for an .except as a more flexible solution in case new fields were added to the address, but ok, I like  your argument for being more verbose and readable too.

Problem is that in this solution new product_locations that use an existing location (as product_location[1] in the original question), the fields get rejected now too, as the location_attributes are not being found. At least that is what I'm seeing now I'm trying your solution.. Or is something else wrong?

Comment: No problem - what does the attributes hash that gets passed into the proc look like in this case?

Comment: The attributes hash has product_locations which use a new location or an existing one, like this:

"product"=>
  {
  "product_locations_attributes"=>
      {        
   "1"=>
    {"location_attributes"=>
     {"_destroy"=>"false", "street"=>"Esmoreitstraat", "number"=>"60", "zipcode"=>"1017 DT", "city"=>"Amsterdam", "country"=>"Netherlands"}, "quantity"=>"3"},
    "2"=>
    {"_destroy"=>"false", "location_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"", "id"=>"110"},
    "3"=>
    {"_destroy"=>"false", "location_id"=>"", "quantity"=>"3"}
   }
  , "commit"=>"Create Product"
  }

1 is new, 2 is existing, 3 is invalid.

Comment: You just need to check whether `location_id` is blank as well - see my updated answer.